# Appending item to an existing Json with Newtonsoft json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have an existing json serialized from a list as below

```
var products= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(produstList, Formatting.Indented);

{
  "Products": [
    {
      "Name": "Sample Product",
      "Id": "LT2134",
      "ProcudtCode": "001KP"
    }
  ]
}
```

Want to apped another serialized json object (ProductList) to the above one like this below, is there a way i can achieve this.

```
{
  "Products": [
    {
      "Name": "Sample Product",
      "Id": "LT2134",
      "ProcudtCode": "001KP"
    }
  ],

   "ProductList": [
    {
      "Category": "Electronics",
      "SubCategory": "Router",
      "ProcudtCode": "001KP",
      "Description": "wifi router",
      "Brand": "test"      
    }
  ]
}
```

Please help me out

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Where are you stuck? This is not really obvious from your question.

Comment: I tried to  append the new json object using Jobject to existing list like below .But not getting a valid json.                                                      JObject jo = JObject.FromObject(produstList);                                       var products = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Products, Formatting.Indented);
jo.Add("ProductsList", products);

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, you can either append the two objects before you do the serialization, or you can mix the two JSON strings afterwards (it really depends on the scenario). I recommend you to create another data model for this or else you may experience problems when de-serializing it.

My recommended solution is:

```
public class MixedProduct {
    public List<Products> Products {get; set;}
    public List<ProductList> ProductList {get; set;}
}

var products= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new MixedProduct { Products = A, ProductList = B}, Formatting.Indented);
```

If for some reasons you cannot or do not want to do this, you can do the following:

```
var products= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Object { Products = A, ProductList = B}, Formatting.Indented);
```

And if you wanna append two JSON string you can do the following:

```
String firstJson = "  { \"Products\": [ {} ]   } ";
String secondJson = "  { \"ProductList\": [ {} ]   } ";
var tempFirst = firstJson.TrimStart().TrimEnd();
var tempSecond = secondJson.TrimStart().TrimEnd();
String mixedJson = "{" + tempFirst.Substring(1, tempFirst.Length - 2) 
                    + "," + tempSecond.Substring(1, tempSecond.Length - 2) + "}";
```

It will be safer to mix them the following way though in order to handle JSON strings that are slightly badly formatted:

```
String mixedJason = "{" + tempFirst.Substring(1, tempFirst.Length - 2).TrimEnd().TrimEnd(',')
                     + "," + tempSecond.Substring(1, tempSecond.Length - 2) + "}";
```